# Calling a MySQL Stored Procedure from a php function with input and output parameters

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, pdo

Now that I've got a great stored procedure solution from wchiquito, I'm having difficulty actually using it to pull any data.

I'm using mysql db with pdo, passing 3 parameters (2 inputs and 1 output).  I've tried it with bindValue and bindParam following the examples from the PHP manual.  However both methods result in errors and I can't see where this is going sideways.

Using bindValue, the following code returns an error of:
"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined' in confirmation.php on line 41". Line 41 is the execute.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("CALL sp_GetUserID(?,?,?)");
$v1 = "tbl_JustSayThanks";
$v2 = "16e90ccf482e72b9a562f5613b659fed";
$v3 = "";
$stmt->bindValue(':tablename_In',$v1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':formSecret_In',$v2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':id_Out',$v3, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($data as $row) {
    return $row['id_Out'];
}
```

Using bindParam, the following code returns an error of:
"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1305 PROCEDURE web_events.sp_GetUserID does not exist' in confirmation.php on line 41". Again, line 41 is the execute.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("CALL sp_GetUserID(?,?,?)");
$v1 = "tbl_JustSayThanks";
$v2 = "16e90ccf482e72b9a562f5613b659fed";
$v3 = "";
$stmt->bindParam(1,$v1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(2,$v2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(3,$v3, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();
$data = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach ($data as $row) {
return $row['id_Out'];
}
```

For reference, here is the stored procedure from wchiquito

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `sp_GetRecordID`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_GetRecordID`(
  `tablename_In` VARCHAR(64),
  `formSecret_In` VARCHAR(32),
  OUT `id_Out` BIGINT UNSIGNED
)
BEGIN
  SET @`query` := CONCAT('SELECT `id` INTO @`id_Out`
                          FROM ', `tablename_In` ,' 
                          WHERE `formSecret` = \'', `formSecret_In`, '\'');
  PREPARE `stmt` FROM @`query`;
  EXECUTE `stmt`;
  SET `id_Out` := @`id_Out`,
       @`query` := NULL;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE `stmt`;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

I'm sure this will be something simple but I'm not seeing it right now and would very much appreciate some help in sorting it out.  Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Where does this procedure reside? In the same exact database that you connect to in PDO?

Comment: In the first instance, it seems reasonable that you would use the named placeholders in the query, e.g. `:tablename_In` instead of the first `?`, etc... but changing this will likely also result in the second error, since it sounds like you may have unintentionally created the procedure in the wrong schema.  `SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS LIKE 'sp_GetUserID';` should show you where it is.

Comment: Well, I'm a moron - the procedure is supposed to be sp_GetRecordID instead of sp_GetUserID - I just did not see that. I'm converting all our web-based forms from MSSQL to MySQL and am changing things a bit. 

That said, once I make that change, I get a new error: 
"Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1414 OUT or INOUT argument 3 for routine gsnetx_web_events.sp_GetRecordID is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger' in confirmation.php on line 44"

Comment: And, I figured out how to make it work but, based on the documentation for pdo procedures and mysql, it shouldn't.  While having output variables worked in the database, by eliminating the output variable in the stored procedure and only passing in the input variables, I was able to get it all to work just fine.  According to the documentation, that shouldn't work, but it does.